# Mirroring effect on images with fade

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I hope you guys can help me. I try to create a mirroring effect on images with a fade. It is working so far but I would like that the mirror image is already at the half (adjustable) complete transparent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,fadings}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]



\def\nodeshadowed[#1]#2;{\node[scale=1,above,#1]{#2};\node[scale=1,
    above,#1,yscale=-1, outer sep=5pt, scope fading=south, opacity=0.3]{#2};}

  \nodeshadowed [at={( 6,-7  )}] {\fbox{\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{ente.jpg}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the link to the "Ente" image, please? And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Thank you... <br/>the link is [link](http://www.schulbilder.org/bild-ente-dl21003.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this meant, but defining a fading style, say `middle`, will provide the fading downto the middle. Please note that due to the mirroring `top` and `bottom` are reversed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,fadings}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{black}

\tikzfading[name=middle,
top color=transparent!0, %completely faded out
bottom color=transparent!100, % use original colour
middle color=transparent!100]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]



\def\nodeshadowed[#1]#2;{%
  \node[scale=1,above,#1]{#2};
  \node[scale=1,above,#1,yscale=-1, outer sep=5pt,scope fading=middle, opacity=0.3]{#2};}
  \nodeshadowed [at={( 6,-7  )}] {\fbox{\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{ente.jpg}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]